# adding values to a sub column with pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

How can I add a subcolumn in a dataframe ?

here is what I have so far...

```
start_date = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=252)
end_date = datetime.today()

stock_list = ['TSLA', 'XOM', 'AAPL']

data = iex.stocks.get_historical_data(stock_list, start_date, end_date, filter=['close'], output_format='pandas')

print(data.head())

data['TSLA']['sma50'] = data['TSLA']['close'].rolling(50).mean()
```

I'm getting this error:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

this is the data:

```
          TSLA                                        XOM                                           AAPL                                        
          open    high     low    close   volume     open     high      low    close    volume      open      high       low     close    volume
date  
2018-04-25  283.50  285.16  277.25  280.690  4013574  75.8561  77.2335  75.1625  77.1171  13865599  160.8679  163.6377  160.6602  161.8868  28382084
2018-04-26  278.75  285.79  276.50  285.480  4356013  77.2141  78.4751  77.1462  78.4363  14554442  162.3518  163.9444  161.6098  162.4507  27963014
2018-04-27  285.37  294.47  283.83  294.075  4364626  74.6435  76.2926  74.1876  75.4584  16346833  162.2330  162.5595  158.8994  160.5711  35655839
2018-04-30  293.61  298.73  292.50  293.900  4228172  75.5748  76.2053  75.4099  75.4196  15028835  160.3834  165.4579  160.0963  163.4795  42427424
2018-05-01  293.51  300.82  293.22  299.920  4625603  74.9443  74.9443  73.7026  74.6435  16231035  164.6173  167.3770  163.4894  167.2781  53569376
```

Desire output

```
             TSLA                                              XOM                                                  AAPL                       
              open    high     low    close   volume sma50     open     high      low    close    volume  sma50    open      high       low     close    volume sma50
```

Comment: desired output? also, [please do not ever post code or data-frame as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: in each column ( TSLA, XOM, AAPL) I want to add a subcolumn ( sma50 )  
putput: (open, high, low, close, volume, sma50) for each column

Comment: Actual data-frame?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the 'Hierarchical indexing (MultiIndex)' functions of pandas.
You should create an array of tuples like this one:

```
index = [('TSLA', 'open'), ('TSLA', 'high'),
         ('TSLA', 'low'), ('TSLA', 'close'),('XOM', 'open'), ('XOM', 'high'),
         ('XOM', 'low'), ('XOM', 'close')] #etc for all of youe stcks....
```

and the a new array of values for each group in the tuple:

```
values = [283.50, 285.16] #etc for all values...
```

Then you should call th Multiindex function of pandas like this:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index)
```

Then you get the dataframe you want by calling:

```
data = pd.Dataframe(data=values,index=index)
```